# How to specify partial object signatures correctly in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

The TypeScript code is based on the Angular 2 Cookbook chapter on dynamic forms - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html

Please, observe:

**question-base.ts**

```
export class QuestionBase<T>{
  value: T;
  key: string;
  label: string;
  required: boolean;
  order: number;
  controlType: string;
  constructor(options: {
    value?: T,
    key?: string,
    label?: string,
    required?: boolean,
    order?: number,
    controlType?: string
  } = {}) {
    this.value = options.value;
    this.key = options.key || '';
    this.label = options.label || '';
    this.required = !!options.required;
    this.order = options.order === undefined ? 1 : options.order;
    this.controlType = options.controlType || '';
  }
}
```

**multi-answer-question-base.ts**

```
import {QuestionBase} from './question-base';

interface AnswerOption {
  key: string;
  value: string;
}

export class MultiAnswerQuestionBase<T> extends QuestionBase<T> {
  answerOptions: AnswerOption[];

  constructor(options: {answerOptions?: AnswerOption[]}) {
    super(options);
    this.answerOptions = options.answerOptions;
  }
}
```

**question-dropdown.ts**

```
import {MultiAnswerQuestionBase} from './multi-answer-question-base';

export class DropdownQuestion extends MultiAnswerQuestionBase<string> {
  controlType = 'dropdown';
}
```

Now I am trying to instantiate `DropdownQuestion` like that:

```
new DropdownQuestion({
    key: 'brave',
    label: 'Bravery Rating',
    order: 3,
    answerOptions: [
        {key: 'solid', value: 'Solid'},
        {key: 'great', value: 'Great'},
        {key: 'good', value: 'Good'},
        {key: 'unproven', value: 'Unproven'}
    ]
});
```

And here TypeScript complaints about the fields key, label and order:

```
Error:(45, 17) TS2345: Argument of type '{ key: string; label: string; order: number; answerOptions: { key: string; value: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ answerOptions?: AnswerOption[]; }'.
 Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'key' does not exist in type '{ answerOptions?: AnswerOption[]; }'.
```

I understand the meaning of this error and I can fix it by either introducing more classes and make my code more similar to C# or Java or just throw away all the types and leave it JavaScript. Neither is a TypeScript way, I suspect.

So, what is the TypeScript way to fix it?

Comment: Since you're dealing with object literals, it is subject to [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) which is preventing you from making that call. Check out the documentation, it tells you how you can get around that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options really.  Since you're dealing with object literals, it is subject to [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) which is preventing you from making that call.  The docs tell you exactly how to get around this.

1. use a type assertion

   ```
   new DropdownQuestion({
       key: 'brave',
       label: 'Bravery Rating',
       order: 3,
       answerOptions: [
           {key: 'solid', value: 'Solid'},
           {key: 'great', value: 'Great'},
           {key: 'good', value: 'Good'},
           {key: 'unproven', value: 'Unproven'}
       ]
   } as {answerOptions?: AnswerOption[]});
   ```
2. add a string index signature to the type

   ```
   constructor(options: {answerOptions?: AnswerOption[], [propName: string]: any}) {
   ```
3. don't use an object literal at the call site, put the params in a separate variable

   ```
   let options = {
       key: 'brave',
       label: 'Bravery Rating',
       order: 3,
       answerOptions: [
           {key: 'solid', value: 'Solid'},
           {key: 'great', value: 'Great'},
           {key: 'good', value: 'Good'},
           {key: 'unproven', value: 'Unproven'}
       ]
   };
   new DropdownQuestion(options);
   ```

But honestly, I don't see the point in having all those extra properties in the first place, they're not even used.  They should be removed.

---

Keep in mind that since the original example used `{}` in the type annotation, it effectively accepted *any* object but with no known named properties.  It used indexers to access the properties which is safe since members of all objects can be accessed by index.  The excess property checks here doesn't apply since no named properties appeared in the annotation.  Since you changed the signature to have them now, you're now getting the error.

If you want to fully understand the issue, refer to [issue 3755](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3755) on GitHub.  If you want to make it work without using the suggestions above, you should follow the pattern of the example and use the indexers to access the members of your objects.  Otherwise, go with the proven solution and add those other properties to the signature and do away with the "partial" signature.

Comment: What do you mean in your last statement? What is not being used?

Comment: Your constructor requires a object which has an optional `answerOptions` property of type `AnswerOption[]`. But you're invoking it using an object literal with extra properties.  What purpose does that serve? The constructor has no use for it and typescript is telling you that it's inclusion doesn't seem right, and it isn't. Much like the same reasons why you can no longer pass in arbitrary amount of arguments to a function unless it explicitly expects it.  If it expects 1 parameter of a certain type, you need to provide it 1 parameter of the expected type, not 2 or 3 parameters.

Comment: But the constructor calls the `super` function to pass the given object to the base class. Is it wrong?

Comment: Ok sure, but your derived class narrowed it down to just that one property.  If your intention is to pass additional properties to down to the base constructors, you need to provide those properties in the signature of the derived class as well. The only reason why the compiler isn't complaining about that is because all your properties on the base class is optional and the absence of those properties satisfies the types.

Comment: Aha, interesting. So, options 1 and 3 are not good, because the DropdownQuestion constructor cripples the passed in object. But the option 2 is good, right? It does not cripple the passed in object? Is there a TypeScript fiddle anywhere? The TypeScript Playground is not very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Given you defined literal types in the constructor, it's best to pass down all this typing to child classes as well. As you expected, creating more classes/interfaces which would make it similar to C#/Java.

> For each class introducing new options, create a new Options type with specific data.

```js
export class QuestionBaseOptions<T> {
    value?: T;
    key?: string;
    label?: string;
    required?: boolean;
    order?: number;
    controlType?: string;
};

export class QuestionBase<T>{
  value: T;
  key: string;
  label: string;
  required: boolean;
  order: number;
  controlType: string;
  constructor(options: QuestionBaseOptions<T> = {}) {
    this.value = options.value;
    this.key = options.key || '';
    this.label = options.label || '';
    this.required = !!options.required;
    this.order = options.order === undefined ? 1 : options.order;
    this.controlType = options.controlType || '';
  }
}

interface AnswerOption {
  key: string;
  value: string;
}

export interface MultiAnswerQuestionBaseOptions<T> extends QuestionBaseOptions<T> {
    answerOptions?: AnswerOption[];
}

export class MultiAnswerQuestionBase<T> extends QuestionBase<T> {
  answerOptions: AnswerOption[];

  constructor(options: MultiAnswerQuestionBaseOptions<T>) {
    super(options);
    this.answerOptions = options.answerOptions;
  }
}

export class DropdownQuestion extends MultiAnswerQuestionBase<string> {
  controlType = 'dropdown';
}

new DropdownQuestion({
    key: 'brave',
    label: 'Bravery Rating',
    order: 3,
    answerOptions: [
        {key: 'solid', value: 'Solid'},
        {key: 'great', value: 'Great'},
        {key: 'good', value: 'Good'},
        {key: 'unproven', value: 'Unproven'}
    ]
});
```